# „Nichts“ im Dativ

Tags: grammar, style, dative

Kann *nichts* im Dativ verwendet werden?

Beispiel (Songzeile aus https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLwd9boEsMw):

> Die Liebe ähnelt nichts.

Das klingt für mich grammatikalisch schief. Ich denke, heute würde man den Dativ umschreiben durch eine Konstruktion wie

> Die Liebe ist ähnlich zu nichts.

Comment: Wobei *zu* hier auch mit dem Dativ steht, insofern wäre wenig gewonnen.

Comment: Gute Frage... in deinem Beispiel würde man wohl einfach sagen "Der Liebe ähnelt nichts (nom)". Die andere Version klingt extrem unelegant für meine Ohren, aber besser als die Version mit "ähnlich"

Comment: Dein Beispiel "Die Liebe ähnelt nichts." ist schlicht falsches Deutsch, korrekt ist: "Der Liebe ähnelt nichts."

Comment: Ich glaube, die präzisere Frage wäre: „Kann _nichts_ **ohne Präposition** im Dativ verwendet werden?“, denn mit kommt es einigermaßen häufig vor.

Answer (score 4):

Auch in der gängigen Phrase

> Von **nichts** kommt nichts.

steht das erste *nichts* im Dativ.

Answer (score 4):

Ja, das kann es. Aber wie Du selbst bemerkst, ist die Wirkung nicht günstig, weil *nichts* nicht flektiert wird und damit das seltene Dativobjekt nicht offen markiert wird. Darunter leidet die Verständlichkeit. In der Praxis würde man also besser sagen

> Die Liebe ähnelt nichts anderem.

oder noch weitergehend umformulieren (z.B. ...ist mit nichts zu vergleichen).